# How to call google map outside a method?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, es6-class

I'm trying to wrap google maps api into a class. The map is loading correctly to the template. Now i would like to add a marker to the map. The problem is how to get the map outside the show() function.

If i do this:

```
export default class InitMap {


    constructor(element) {

        this.element = element;

    }

    show() 
    {

        let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.element), this.options());

        this.addMarker();

        console.log(this.addMarker()); //undefined
    }

    options() 
    {

        return {

            zoom: 4,

            center: { lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044 },

            disableDefaultUI: true,

            zoomControl: true,

            scaleControl: false,

            streetViewControl: false,

            rotateControl: false,

            fullscreenControl: true

        }

    }

    marker(location) 
    {

        return new google.maps.Marker({

          position: location,

          map: map,

          title: 'test'

        });

    }

    addMarker() 
    {

        let uluru = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363, 131.044);

        this.marker(uluru);

    }


}
```

I'm getting an error:

> setMap: not an instance of Map;

Is it possible to set the map to a property in a class ? Or how can i access it outside the `show()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a private property for map instance in the class and reuse it when necessary.

The following code should be fine

```
export default class InitMap {
    private element;
    private map = null;

    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    show() {
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.element), this.options());
        this.addMarker();
    }

    options() {
        return {
            zoom: 4,
            center: { lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044 },
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            scaleControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            rotateControl: false,
            fullscreenControl: true
        }
    }

    marker(location) {
        return new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          map: this.map,
          title: 'test'
        });
    }

    addMarker() {
        let uluru = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363, 131.044);
        this.marker(uluru);
    }
}
```

You can see working example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fgugag?embed=1&file=map.ts

I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you. my solution was: i added in the constructor `window.map = this;` but i think your solution i a better joice because i set the map globally ?